# Ember.js: use body-parser library in mocking backend with mirage

Tags: ember.js, body-parser, ember-cli-mirage

I'm developing Ember.js application that authenticates against OAuth2 endpoint.

In order to mock this endpoint, I use `ember-cli-mirage` that needs to parse HTTP POST having `content-type` of `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I decided to use `body-parser` npm package in order to parse the body of the request.

Currently I have this code in my `config.js`:

```
  var urlencodedParser = BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

  this.post('/login', (schema, request) => {
  });
```

I know that `request.requestBody` contains the data I'd like to parse, but I just can't find the correct way to make use of 'urlencodedParser` in order to parse this data.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const requestPayload = JSON.parse(request.requestBody);
```

Headers can be found in `request.requestHeaders`. You don't need 3rd-party library for this.